# A little challenging but an interesting topic

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

We have to Write an InputFormat and RecordReader
 that read strings of text 
**separated by '$' characters instead of newlines**.
Now suppose we have a dataset like
$`<some data>`$`<some data>`

we want to use the first $ as delimiter and we have to exempt the mid "dollar" sign from making it a delimiter.

Could you please suggest the necessary functions or necessary steps to make this happen?

**Thankyou in advance**

Comment: can you give a example with proper input and desired output

Comment: I, unfortunately cannot provvide you the data due to company privacy as the data is a banking data.
By the way I have provided you with the exact format of the data. In the some data part you  may take any values such as

Comment: $Aniruddha Sinha$23$Hadoop$mapreduce$Kishore$30$Hadoop$mapreduce

Comment: it mean you need Aniruddha Sinha as first line, 23 in second line, Hadoop in third line and so on. is am right. let me know is other requirement.

Comment: No!, that's the trick. You need to  take Anirudddha Sinha,23mhadoop in the first line and kishor 30 hadoop mapreduce in the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input file

```
$Aniruddha Sinha$23$Hadoop$mapreduce$Kishore$30$Hadoop$mapreduce
```

output file

```
Aniruddha Sinha,23,Hadoop,mapreduce
Kishore,30,Hadoop,mapreduce
```

code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SkipBadRecords;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    private int count = 0;
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      if(count < 4){
          sb.append(value.toString());
          sb.append(",");
          count++;
          if(count == 4){
              System.out.println(sb.substring(0, sb.length()-1));
              count = 0;
              word.set(sb.substring(0, sb.length()-1));
              context.write(word, one);
              sb.delete(0, sb.length());
          }
      }
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "$");
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    SkipBadRecords.setMapperMaxSkipRecords(conf, 10);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("/home/kishore/input"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/kishore/output"));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Please up vote it if you find the question a cool one